# tool tip does not display properly in IE?

Tags: html

I have below code.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="bgimg" valign="middle" width="10%" title="some title" nowrap>
            <img src="images/SomeLogo.gif"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If I place the mouse pointer on the image then tool tip "some title" is displayed. if i move out of the logo quickly and come back and place the pointer on logo, then also it displays. **The only time i observed tool tip not displaying is place the mouse pointer on the logo for some time(around 10 secs) then tool tip is disappeared automatically and never displays the tool tip again if i place the mouse pointer on the logo.** if i refresh the browser again it displays but if i keep the cursor for few seconds on the logo then same problem. but in Firefox it works well. what is an issue here? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it for the `img` as well:

```
<td class="bgimg" valign="middle" width="10%" title="some title" nowrap>
    <img src="images/SomeLogo.gif" title="some title" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are billions of jQuery-Plugins can be used to overcome the limitations and cross browser problems of `alt` and `title` "tooltips". If you're already using jquery in your project, this may be a better solution.

Here are some very cool looking examples: [30 Stylish jQuery Tooltip Plugins](http://1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/)